# Customized single-player match in Worms World Party?

Tags: worms-world-party

I am playing "Worms World Party: Remastered" on my PC, remembering the old days, but I cannot find a command in the menu to play the single-player game against the computer, using a custom map and crate settings. (This is *not* the "hot-seat" game with friends.)

I don't remember if I ever played like that before, but how can I do that, if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** The customized single-player match is actually in the two-player menu:

[image]

There are four commands in the main menu:

- Go to the single player menu
- Create a single or multi-player game *(this is the one you want)*
- Play over a local area network or the Internet
- Go to the options menu

The picture with **one worm** is for a "quick game" (no custom maps or crate settings) and missions
The picture with **two worms** is also for a single player game against the computer + custom options

Yes, there are only four options, but this still gets me every time: I always click the one worm, thinking that is for all types of single-player games, and then wander around inside that menu endlessly.

---

#### Create a single or multi-player game

This allows for the following custom options:

- Terrain
- Scheme options

Under "Scheme options", there are two large picture buttons:

- Set or view the weapon options *(adjust Ammo, Delay, Power, Crates)*
- Set or view the game options *(adjust additional create and time options, including time between players in a "hot-seat" game)*

When choosing teams, you can choose multiple human and computer teams. If you choose multiple human teams, this will start a "hot-seat" game with friends. Otherwise, you are simply creating a single player game against the computer.